# f:viewParam and f:viewMethod not calling (jsf)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

As I know `<f:viewParam>` we use for GET parameter.

Also I  know  `<f:viewAction ...>`  we can use for acess check usually for each specific situation (for specific view/bean).  As well as     calls at the beginning. So I’ve done. Specifically I have a bean - ViewScopedBean myBean.  And a view (.xhtml)  which includes

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="param" value="#{viewScopedBean.param}" />
    <f:viewAction action="#{viewScopedBean.doCheck()}" />
</f:metadata>
```

But Setter and method are not call.

I use  JSF 2.2.9.

And I try change namespaces `xmlns.jcp.org` and `java.sun.com`. But i’ve not received results.

Could you help me with this question? What should I check? What should I do for correct result?

Thanks a lot for you attention and help.

Comment: `f:viewMethod`?

Comment: Getter & setter for `viewScopedBean.param` has to have the same types.

Comment: setter & getter has a String type.